# Get the Middle Value of the Column

Tags: teradata

I have Certain records in my Column as below

```
Col1
G XXXXX AB
G XXX XXX AB
G XXX XXXXX AB
G XXX AB
```

Scenario is to get everything in the middle if it starts with G and ends with AB

so Resultwould be some thing like this

```
XXXXX
XXX XXX
XXX XXXXX
XXX
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try removing the leading `G` and trailing `AB` from matching records using a regex replacement:

```
SELECT
    Col1,
    REGEXP_REPLACE(Col1, '^G\s*|\s*AB$', '') AS Col1_Middle
FROM yourTable
WHERE
    Col1 LIKE 'G%AB';
```

[image: screen capture of demo below]

### Demo

If you only want records starting with `G` followed by a space, and ending with `AB` preceded by a space, then use the following `WHERE` clause instead:

```
WHERE Col1 LIKE 'G % AB'
```

Demo given using Oracle (there are no web based Teradata demo tools), but the syntax should also work with Teradata.

Comment: Thank you @Tim Biegeleisen . It helped